# So I'm working on a Java library for Magic: the Gathering

Tags: discussion, on-topic, magic-the-gathering

...And I wasn't sure what to do about it, because it seems like it would be off-topic here for being about programming, but it would be off-topic at Programmers.SE for being about a card game.

Basically, I'm looking for some help with some of the harder parts of writing this software, so I was thinking of starting a chat room to see if anyone was interesting in discussing the finer points Magic mechanics, such as whether a colorless mana symbol is really a symbol.  But I wasn't which site to start it under, or even if it's a good idea.  Is there a good way to handle this?

### Edit: [Initial release of the library on GitHub](https://github.com/c0d3br34k3r/magic/)

I don't feel super-confident about the state it's in, but I just need to get it out there, and I think it's good enough.  I'd certainly appreciate any feedback, from the people who answered/ commented on this, and of course anyone else who's interested.

Comment: This has been bugging me, so I have to say it: I think I know Magic pretty well, and I have no idea what you mean by your example discussion point ("whether a colorless mana symbol is really a symbol").

Comment: @murgatroid99 Well, certain cards count mana symbols, but no card counts colorless mana in a cost.  It's the only type of symbol that doesn't have a symbol, only a number.  And unlike all other symbols, it's not repeated to show how much there is.  This is reflected in how my manacost data structure works.  Basically, I have a Symbol enum, and colorless is not included.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first sentence, but it seems like "converted mana cost" is exactly this. But, for the rest, colorless mana symbols are in fact symbols: see [rule 107.4](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Numbers_and_symbols) for details.

Comment: I don't mean that they're not technically symbols according to the rules of the game, but that they behave in a much different way than other symbols.  I really should release my current version of the library so people like you can offer criticism, I'm just trying to figure out how to reach a decent number of people who would be interested in checking it out.  And by the first sentence, I meant devotion/ chroma, basically.

Comment: In that case, I'll just refer to Rainbolt's answer: you have to divide your question into questions based on the rules of Magic and questions about how to program it. Also, I would be interested in both looking at your code and discussing it in our chat room.

Comment: It sounds like the "is it a symbol" question is actually a programming one - you're thinking about how to represent all the attributes of a card in code, and noticing that some parts of the game (devotion) care about some of those attributes but not others.

Comment: @Jefromi Yeah, I think you're right, and it's questions like these that make me think only people who are both Magic players and Java programmers can help.  There are some issues I just don't think I break down enough for non-Magic players to help with.

Comment: @codebreaker People who are both would certainly be *better* at it, but I think if you work at it you'll be able to explain what you're trying to do to the programming crowd well enough to get useful advice - and the process of figuring out how to explain it may well lead you to the answers without ever having to post a question, analogous to [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @codebreaker I have experience in both Magic and programming (and writing Magic related programs), so I think I'd be able to help. If you join our chat room (which Rainbolt linked to), I'd be happy to discuss it.

Comment: Okay, cool, thanks, I'll try to release it in a few days, and I'll let you know.  I definitely agree on the rubber duck thing, I just think that, in object oriented design, modeling something in the most representative way possible often requires knowledge of both the programming language and the thing you're modeling.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Post updated with a link to my code (not sure if you get notified by the edit itself)

Comment: As I said before, I would suggest going into our chat room, which Rainbolt linked to, if you want to discuss it.

Comment: Would it be better to create a separate chat room, or just use the main one?

Comment: Either one would work. The main chat room is pretty quiet, so using it wouldn't be very disruptive

Answer (score 9):

**Where can I get casual help?**

You can always join [Board and Card Games chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games) or [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) (Programming chat) to casually discuss pretty much anything.

**Where can I get help?**

For more involved questions, we'll start off by stating the obvious:

- Ask your programming questions on Programming.
- Ask your Magic: the Gathering questions on Board & Card Games.

**I have a combo question that deals with more than one topic. What do I do?**

Break your combo questions into their respective parts. For example:

> What data structure should I use to model the turn structure in Magic: the Gathering?

This question would be hard for a card game expert to answer, and it would be hard for a programming expert to answer. Break it down.

> How does the turn structure work in Magic: the Gathering?

This is a perfect question for Board and Card Games SE. You'll get well-written answers from card game experts.

> I need to model *[insert lengthy, detailed description of the Magic turn structure]*. What data structure should I use to model this?

This question is self-contained and on topic for Programming SE. You should get well written answers from programming experts.

You might save yourself a little time and effort by forcing your multi-topic question onto one site or another. If you get lucky, someone who is an expert on both topics will write you a beautiful answer. Regardless, your best bet is to ask focused questions that target focused audiences.

Answer (score 5):

**Note: Programmers changed names to Software Engineering since this answer was originally posted.**

[Software Engineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) regular here.

As far as the programming aspects go, there are three sites that might help. In each case, questions about the game mechanics are off-topic. However, it is perfectly fine to say "I am working on a library for M:TG. Here is a game element I am trying to model. Just to be clear, I need help with the programming aspect of the problem, not the game/rules aspect." One of us might already know the problem domain (M:TG) and have good background. If not, we will now have a good idea of what your goal is.

### [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

- Design review. Here is a class or other diagram for modeling my problem: does anyone have feedback? [Be specific](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6504/): enumerate your concerns, ask specific questions about how it could be improved.

### [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

- [Code problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This code does not work (copy/paste/format code into question). I am trying to accomplish XYZ. How do I fix it?

### [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

- Code improvement. This code works, but I feel it could be better. Anyone have feedback? If you make recommended changes and are still not satisfied, [post a new question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/), do not update your old one, and edit links between the questions into the question body.

Questions about algorithms are on-topic at both Software Engineering and Stack Overflow, but you are likely to get a better response at Software Engineering despite the smaller audience.

No matter what you post, *be specific*. The software development sites as a whole tend to attract questions that get closed as "too broad" which helps nobody.

You may need to break up a question into multiple questions (even across multiple sites) to meet quality guidelines. If in doubt, see my next point:

Finally, we have...

### [The Whiteboard (Software Engineering.SE chat)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard)

- It is safe to ask off-topic or "too broad" questions here. You might not get an answer, but it is chat, not Q&A.
- We can help hone your question into a good, on-topic question even if it is not for our site. The regulars in our chat are also experienced with Stack Overflow and Code Review and can help you ask a question at those sites.

### See also

- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't consider Code Review.  I'm not sure if you get notified when I edit my question, but I posted the link to my library if you're interested.